# Problem solving approach by hindus

Tags: rituals

When a hindi is seriously inflected by problems, some take the prashne way. It cud be of any time. And many times answers are similiar type - stree shapa, untimely death in family, family diety not satisfied, death of bachelor, spinister. Some I have seen are quite gud in deciphering the problem. But I believe in other kind of prashne. Question people in ur bloodline and find the answer. And I did it with 3 families and found the answers matching with the people who took prashne marga.
I am still skeptic about this prashne marga. Can anyone tell me how these prashne rituals got prominenace and acceptance.

Comment: It shud be hindu, not hindi